# PyQGIS Processing: "memory: not found"

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, algorithm, qgis-3

I try to run a QGIS plugin in QGIS 3.4 that uses processing to execute algorithms in a row:

```
    params_snap = {
        'input' : input,
        'type' : 1,
        'tool' : 1,
        'threshold' : 0.000095,
        'output': 'memory:',
        'error' : error,
        'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 2
    }

    snap = processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:v.clean', params_snap)

    params_break = {
        'input': snap['output'],
        'type': 1,
        'tool': 0,
        'threshold': 0,
        'output': output,
        'error': error,
        'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 2
    }

    processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:v.clean', params_break)
```

First the v.clean snap algorithm runs. The result is saved in a temporary output layer. This algorithm work without any problems. Afterwards I try to run v.clean break and the input should be the temporarily saved output layer of the first algorithm. But I get the error: `Could not load source layer for input: memory: not found.`

If I use a filepath instead of `'memory:'` in the first output everything works fine and the second algorithm can access the first algorithms output. So I assume that the problem is the `'memory:'` statement, but all the sources I found tell to use it.

**Edit:**

I checked the temporary folder (`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_83c42fa467d2461eb67590c719fc22aa\grassdata\temp_location\PERMANENT\vector`) and the layer gets successfully created when I run the code. But since it is not located directly in the path `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\` I wonder if the path the temporary files are created in is the right one?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a name for the memory layer?

Comment: Yes, same error. 'memory: name' not found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grass provider does not support QGIS memory layers, so you'll need to give it a path to a real location it can store the temporary result as.