# PyQGIS processing: Overwrite not possible

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, grass-gis, algorithm

I have a QGIS plugin that runs the v.clean algorithm two times (first time `snap`, second `break`) on a chosen layer:

```
    output = self.dlg.directory.text()

    params_snap = {
        'input' : input,
        'type' : 1,
        'tool' : 1,
        'threshold' : 0.000095,
        'output': output,
        'error' : error,
        '--overwrite': True,
        'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 2
    }
    processing.run('grass7:v.clean', params_snap)

    params_break = {
        'input': output,
        'type': 1,
        'tool': 0,
        'threshold': 0.1,
        '-c': True,
        'output': output,
        'error': error,
        '--overwrite': True,
        'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 2
    }
    processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:v.clean', params_break)
```

My problem is that after running snap, the created output file is not overwritten. `runAndLoadResults` of the break algorithm loads the output file as expected, but without broken lines. So only `snap` was applied. Since `--overwrite` is `True` it should work, or do I miss something?

If I choose another output file for the break algorithm everything runs perfect, so the problem is not the algorithm itself.

As stated in my other question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310148/pyqgis-processing-memory-not-found), a temporary output is not possible for Grass algorithms and therefore no solution.

**EDIT:** The processing log messages print an error:

```
2019-01-30T11:59:16     INFO    C:\Windows\System32>v.out.ogr -c type="line"
input="output6c3d7544cb524a2486d97aca71a41bc4" output="C:\Users\USER
\Desktop\test.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
2019-01-30T11:59:16     CRITICAL    ERROR 1: A file system object called  
'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test.gpkg' already exists.
```

So Grass recognizes overwrite, but it does not work. Is this the wrong command, for what I try to achieve? The algorithm help (`processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:v.clean")`) gives no information about overwrites. I got the information from the [v.clean manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.clean.html).

Comment: I do not know about coding yet, and there are many users who do. But I can offer you my perspective as a user. If I want to run a similar command in GRASS, I get the same error. The option to overwrite, for me, means that the output file can be pre-existing, but not that it is in use by the same command. I can not give a command the same input file as output. On the other hand, I can give it a pre-existing file and overwrite it, as long as it is not the same input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the same file for the input and output parameters.

If I try to run a similar command in the GRASS *v.clean* algorithm from QGIS, I get the same error.

The overwrite option means that the output file can pre-exist, and it works fine as long as the file itself is not open or in use by the same algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using the right technical words in my answer. Editions to my answer or more detailed answers from more experienced users are welcome.